# How to assign an app to specific workspace with XFCE?

Tags: xfce, workspaces

I would like to assign apps to workspaces, so every time an app is launched, it starts in specific workspace that it's assigned to. I'm using XFCE4 on Arch Linux.

Comment: This question is marked as duplicate, the "duplicate" mentions GNOME this one mentions XFCE.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The question clearly relates to XFCE. Using WM independent workarounds such as Devilspie isn't what the author asked for.